# How to create bar chart with geomean, mean, max and min from data using Plotnine

Tags: python, python-ggplot, plotnine

How to create bar chart with gmean, mean, max and min stats for each category.
For the data below,

| X | B | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | b1 | 4 |
| A1 | b2 | 2 |
| A1 | b3 | 3 |
| A1 | b4 | 8 |
| A2 | b1 | 7 |
| A2 | c1 | 10 |
| A2 | c2 | 8 |
| A2 | b3 | 7 |
| A3 | b4 | 10 |
| A3 | b5 | 9 |
| A3 | b1 | 4 |
| A3 | b3 | 1 |

The chart should look like,
[image]

Comment: Please be specific as to what language/library you are trying to use as well as including your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepare(calculate the aggregates) the data you want to visualise.

```
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import ggplot, aes, geom_col
from scipy.stats import gmean
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

# Original Data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "X": sorted(("A1", "A2", "A3") * 4),
    "Y": [4, 2, 3, 8, 7, 10, 8, 7, 10, 9, 4, 1]
})

# Calculate the aggregates
df2 = (df.groupby("X")
 .agg({"Y": [gmean, "mean", "max", "min"]})
 .unstack()
 .reset_index()
 .rename(columns={0: "value", "level_1": "agg"})
)

# Order the aggregates
df2["agg"] = df2["agg"].astype(CategoricalDtype(["gmean", "mean", "max", "min"]))

(ggplot(df2, aes("X", "value", fill="agg"))
 + geom_col(position="dodge")
)
```

[image]

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to do it entirely in plotnine, but it seems not possible. Thank you for your answer